# Try to install php 73 but it installs php 74

Tags: centos, php, php7

I had php 7.4.10 in my centos 7 server but I want to downgrade to php 7.3
I uninstalled the php 7.4 and tried this code.

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
yum install yum-utils 
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73
yum install php php-opcache php-gd php-curl php-mysqlnd
yum update -y
php -v
```

no matter what I do, I see that php 7.4.11 is installed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum install` installs the latest PHP available. Since you have newer PHP 7.4 already installed, `yum` keeps what it has because it sees PHP 7.3 in the enabled repositories.

To downgrade, you can try:

```
yum downgrade php*
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I downgrade to 7.3?

Comment: first ti me it downgraded to 7.4.10, second time it downgraded to 7.3

Comment: @DavSev, the first time it downgraded to 7.4 still because I guess you have its repo enabled. 7.4 repo should be disabled with `yum-config-manager --enable remi-php74` if you want to be on PHP 7.3.